# iPhone photos size problem,

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-device-management

I am using iPhone 7.And total space is 32GB,and i duplicates 5000 photos into 50000.And when i went and see the iPhone storage, it's showing total capacity 32GB,free space 0 and photos part occupied 54GB.I am confused and posting this Question.How is it possible to store 54GB in 32GB device.Please help me.

Comment: Can you post an image of what you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to store 54GB in 32GB of space. It sounds like it is erroneously displaying how much space it wants to fit all the images. File systems mark memory as allocated before transferring to them, which could be why you are getting strange numbers.