# How is an iPhone able to hold more than its stated capacity?

Tags: iphone, ios, storage

What’s going on here? Why the huge discrepancy? And why can I still keep writing data to my iPhone?

[image]

Optimize storage is not turned on. iCloud is off.

Comment: Settings > photos ... is optimize storage turned on?  If so, the phone will keep thumbnails of the pictures on the phone and originals on iCloud.

Comment: What is your iOS version?

Comment: A similar question was asked recently https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320111/iphone-photos-size-problem/320175#320175. It may be that the storage image for Photos is buggy.